# Stuck in emergency mode

Tags: boot

I can't login on Ubuntu, this is what I get!

```
Welcome to emergency mode! 
After logging in type 'journalctl -xb' to view system logs, 
'systemctl reboot' to reboot or ^D to try again to boot into default mode. 
Press enter for maintenance (or Control-D to continue)
```

But it won't continue. I am still getting stuck! I also got:

```
[sdc] No caching mode found 
[sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
```

I made an update before as it showed my there was one available, now I can't get to my desktop anymore, I still have that bootable USB.

Comment: Will you edit your question and add the output of `sudo lsblk -o name,mountpoint,label,size,fstype,uuid;sudo parted -l`.  Using a live media.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/OCUoUJjh.jpg

Comment: Did you install Windows on this drive after Ubuntu had been installed?  Also, are you able to boot into Windows from this drive?  Also, adding the text (copying and pasting) from the live media to your question would make it much easier to read and copy the text for text searches in looking for how resolutions were handled by others.

Comment: I have only elementaryOS on my laptop (based on ubuntu last version), I can't copy and paste because I can't enter to the desktop. Right now I have to functionally os..

Comment: Can you answer the other parts of the comment/question?  Was `Windows` installed after or before Linux?  Does Windows boot into Windows?

Comment: Win10 was firstly installed on this machine. After that I erased win and replaced it with linux

Comment: Elemetary OS isn't supported on `Askubuntu`.  You'll have to use one of the support forums such as http://superuser.com or http://unix.stackexchange.com for support.

Comment: It's almost the same thing, but lighter. The settings I used on ubutuntu worked as well on eOS..

Comment: Linux distributions have much in similarity.  They are all based on Unix.  I have asked for moderation support to have the question moved to the proper forum.  This way you won't have to retype the question.

Comment: I got the same problems on ubuntu as well, I'll try to reinstall another version or switch back  to win.  Linux doesn't behave that Nice on my device, sadly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45795/discussion-between-l-d-james-and-razvan-alex).

Answer (score 0):

I could provide support for Ubuntu, but the steps may not work on some of the other distros, to start out with, you've already mentioned it doesn't have the Live boot option for performing the configuration that is available using USB.  I'm sure the ElementaryOS guru's have similar steps that with their distributed tools to resolve installation issues.  As far as working on devices, so far I haven't seen any computer that Linux didn't work on.

Comment: It's working, but with a lot of issues..should it Be the UEFI's fault?

Comment: No.  Unless you UEFI supported hardware with UEFI activated, UEFI has nothing to do with the environment.  It's not being used.  Online the Legacy part.